# How to enable/turn on Rich Text editor in SharePoint server 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, rich-text, image, richhtmlfield

By default, when I try to create custom list with column I do not get the option to set the column type as Rich Text. 
Neither can I see the option while I try to add an item to that list subsequently.

Is there some place I need to turn this on vefore it shows up across the system?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

It is probably due to the fact that you already have a site content type in use that you want to add the column to that content type. You need to add a new content type and add it in place of the old one as described [here](http://www.sharepointsingh.com/2010/07/add-multiline-rich-textenhanced-rich.html).

You also should be able to add it programmatically through C# (which can be translated to powershell) described [here](http://www.hansrasmussen.com/rich-text-editor-not-displaying/).

```
        SPSite site = new SPSite("http://sharepoint");
        SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb();

        SPList lib = web.Lists["Your list goes here"];

        SPFieldMultiLineText field = 
                (SPFieldMultiLineText)lib.Fields["Your RTF Column"]; // this is your site column
        field.RichText = true;
        field.Update();
```

**EDIT**: You can also add a list column and add that list column to the list instance of the content type, which would be much easier if your scope allows that.

Comment: updated my answer.